# Building a Autonomous pesticide spraying system using swarm robotics based on odor (volatile Organic Compounds) detection

Tags: sensors, research

Visible worms, pests, and diseased parts of plants emit a unique odor (Volatile Organic compounds with different concentrations). I understand that sensors which can quantitatively detect these compounds development are being developed. My idea is to build a swarm of robots which can spray pesticides by detecting VOCs on three targets present on plants across the fields.

1. Target 1: Visible worms, pests, larvae. May these can be mechanically eliminated
2. Target 2: Invisible pathogens on certain areas of a plant
3. Target 3: Areas where pesticides have to be sprayed to prevent disease

For these targets, pesticide has to be administered in the correct concentration 
This idea can optimize the use of pesticides and treat the plant properly 
Questions:

1. Is swarm robotics still sci-fi or Did any one implement it?
2. Are the  any specific scenarios where implemented swarm robotic systems  are coming to help and establish the ease?
3. Which is the implemented system or idea in conception that can help in formation of solution for the above problem?
4. How much time is required approximately to realize this idea?

Hope this question does not sound sci-fi and is practical and the intention is to solve a definite problem 
How can i work by following some steps to further  make this idea concrete

Comment: Start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aroma

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* user1394, but from our [faq]: *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site*. Check out [ask] and [about] for a good introduction for how stack exchange works.